# Does Amazon RDS for SQL Server support SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, amazon-rds

Reading some conflicting answers from Google searches, not sure if the answer is Yes, No, or maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought it was pretty clear when reading [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html):

> Amazon RDS currently does not support the following SQL Server features:
>
> The ability to run Reporting, Analysis, Integration, or Master Data Services on the same server as the DB instance. If you need to do this, we recommend that you either install SQL Server on an EC2 instance or use an on-premise SQL Server instance to act as the Reporting, Analysis, Integration, or Master Data Services server.

Comment: Gotcha -- It would have helped if Amazon explicitly referred to Integration Servers as SSIS (I wouldn't have missed that in my search).

Comment: Agreed, this page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html for searchability could have just had (SSIS/SSAS/SSRS) as part of that sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon now supports SSIS on RDS as of May 2020.

[More info here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/using-microsoft-sql-server-integration-services-on-amazon-rds-for-sql-server/)