# How to replicate Production MSSQL DB into Test db on a daily basis

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-replication

I'm using RDS SQL Server database for my live environment. 
I'd need to fully replicate the database into another RDS database on a fixed frecuency (maybe daily). The goal is to have test environment always provisioned with latest real data (cualitative and cuantitative) in order to make tests meaninfull.

How can I get this done in AWS? 
NOTE: db footprint about 20Gb

Comment: Simplest way - create a task or job that takes a prod backup, restores to test environment, scrubs data if needed (anything PII), and adjusts permissions.

Comment: would you please expand?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SQL Server Integration Services project that will copy the entire database from one environment to the other. You can schedule it as a Job. You should investigate using the Transfer Database Task.

Comment: SSIS not supported in RDS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30057091/does-amazon-rds-for-sql-server-support-ssis

Answer (score -2):

Your tests should not use production data. Not only is it a waste of processing/money, it also doesn't have any justification for it and is bad practice. You should know what your production data looks like and have a test table with that data, and only update that data if there is a change to how you process the data.

Comment: Sorry I disagree. Waste of processing/money is subjective.  It can be bad practice if there is automated testing in place, but I can tell you many organizations do not have that in place. Oftentimes, data fresh from prod + scrubbing is much cheaper than creating dummy data.

Comment: Waste of proccesing/money was only one of the reasons I mentioned, the other is there is no real reason to do it. It also poses a security risk, even if you scrub the data you are still connecting your production environment with your testing environment. It's bad practice any way you look at it...there is a reason environments are segregated.

Comment: Again, it's a security risk, but depends on your data. Further, your initial response does not answer the OPs question.

Comment: It's also a waste of money to test and migrate changes that fail in prod because there wasn't a close enough reproduction of the prod workload.

Comment: Access control matrix is replicated into dev and devs are already able to access prod (no silos)
The main non functional requirement is performance so we need to develop with the same data load in mind. creating random relational data for a 120 clases model would become a  real overhead